# React Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, state, setstate

I'm fetching **employees** collection into **employees** state:

```
...
  const [employees, setEmployees] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const getEmployees = async () => {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/get-employees");
      const data = await response.json();
      setEmployees(data);
    };
    getEmployees();
  }, []);

...
```

The state will look like this:

```
employees:[
{ _id:13413413413,nameAR:"عاصم شوشاري",nameEN:"aasem shoshari",title:"front-end software engineer" }
{ _id:13413413413,nameAR:"عاصم شوشاري",nameEN:"aasem shoshari",title:"front-end software engineer" }
{ _id:13413413413,nameAR:"عاصم شوشاري",nameEN:"aasem shoshari",title:"front-end software engineer" }
]
```

Then displaying the data into html table:

```
return:(
        <table>
          <tr key={"header"}>
            { Object.keys(employees[0]).map((key) => <th>{key}</th>)}
          </tr>
          { employees.map((employee) => (
              <tr key={employee._id}>
                {Object.values(employee).map((val) => (
                  <td>{val}</td>
                ))}
              </tr>
            ))}
        </table>
)
```

it looks like the state value will take some time to be fetched, therefore the `Object.keys(employees[0])` will be **null** for some time and the application will crash and it says **Cannot convert undefined or null to object**

although im using **useEffect** isn't suppose that the component will re-render on state change, then will it crash anyway therefore you need a way to tell the component to wait for the state? but how

Comment: In your `useState` initialization you can use `[{}]` instead of `[]` to avoid this error.

Comment: It's not related to React, `Object.keys` throw that error and you can not do anything about it. easy fix will be changing `useState([]);` to `useState([{}]);`

Comment: although i dont know how it worked, but it worked! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont display the rows in the table until employees is populated.

```
return( 
       {employees.length > 0 ??
        <table>
          <tr key={"header"}>
            { Object.keys(employees[0]).map((key) => <th>{key}</th>)}
          </tr>
          {employees.map((employee) => (
              <tr key={employee._id}>
                {Object.values(employee).map((val) => (
                  <td>{val}</td>
                ))}
              </tr>
            ))}
        </table> : <p>not ready</p>}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, once data is fetched and `employees` state value set, the component will re-render. But until then, you need to handle the initial state, when `employees` is undefined.

The simplest way to do that would be:

```
if (employees) {
  return <table>...</table>;
} else {
  return <div>Loading...</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to always set loader if you call API

```
const [employees, setEmployees] = useState([{}]);
const [loader,setLoader] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    const getEmployees = async () => {
      setLoader(true);
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/get-employees");
      const data = await response.json();
      setLoader(false);
      setEmployees(data);
    };
    getEmployees();
  }, []);
```

after setLoader

```
return(
     <>
        { loader? <div>Loading....</div> :(<table>
          <tr key={"header"}>
            { Object.keys(employees[0]).map((key) => <th>{key}</th>)}
          </tr>
          { employees.map((employee) => (
              <tr key={employee._id}>
                {Object.values(employee).map((val) => (
                  <td>{val}</td>
                ))}
              </tr>
            ))}
        </table>)
     </>
)
```